# Double Jump in unity 2D and code optimization

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm an absolute beginner in Unity and C# and I'm having some issues inserting a double jump on my Unity 2D Project. My question is: How can I be able to add a double jump on this code?
I tried to follow a lot of tutorials on internet, but I wasn't successful in any of the tutorials. This code I'm using right now is working normally, but I need to add the double jump function on the game.
Here's the code I'm using, I really need some help.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D rigidbody;
    private BoxCollider2D collider;
    private SpriteRenderer sprite;
    private Animator animator;


    [SerializeField] private LayerMask jumpableGround;

    private float dirX = 0f;
    [SerializeField]private float PlayerMovementSpeed = 7f;
    [SerializeField]private float PlayerJumpSpeed = 8f;

    private enum MovementState { idle, running, jumping, falling }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        collider = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
        sprite = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {
        dirX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(dirX * PlayerMovementSpeed, rigidbody.velocity.y);

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && IsGrounded())
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(0, PlayerJumpSpeed);
        }
        
        UpdateAnimationState();
    }

    private void UpdateAnimationState()
    {
        MovementState state;

        if (dirX > 0f)
        {
            state = MovementState.running;
            sprite.flipX = false;
        }
        else if (dirX < 0f)
        {
            state = MovementState.running;
            sprite.flipX = true;
        }
        else
        {
            state = MovementState.idle;
        }

        if (rigidbody.velocity.y > .1f)
        {
            state = MovementState.jumping;
        }
        else if (rigidbody.velocity.y < -.1f)
        {
            state = MovementState.falling;
        }

        animator.SetInteger("state", (int)state);
    }

    private bool IsGrounded()
    {
       return Physics2D.BoxCast(collider.bounds.center, collider.bounds.size, 0f, Vector2.down, .1f, jumpableGround);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you stuck on implementing a double-jump functionality? This code looks like it is easily adaptable to implement a double-jump, but it looks like it comes from a tutorial. Have you tried writing your own code and run into bugs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way to make this in your code is adding a counter of jumps, the variable starts in 0 and adds 1 to value on every jump, then you reset de variable when the character in on ground.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D rigidbody;
    private BoxCollider2D collider;
    private SpriteRenderer sprite;
    private Animator animator;


    [SerializeField] private LayerMask jumpableGround;

    private float dirX = 0f;
    [SerializeField]private float PlayerMovementSpeed = 7f;
    [SerializeField]private float PlayerJumpSpeed = 8f;

    private enum MovementState { idle, running, jumping, falling }

    // NEW VARIABLE
    private int jumpCounter;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        collider = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
        sprite = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        jumpCounter = 0;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {
        dirX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(dirX * PlayerMovementSpeed, rigidbody.velocity.y);
        //THE CONDITION CHANGES
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && jumpCounter<2)
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(0, PlayerJumpSpeed);
            jumpCounter++;
        }
        if(IsGrounded())
        {
          jumpCounter = 0;
        }
    enter code here
        UpdateAnimationState();
    }

    private void UpdateAnimationState()
    {
        MovementState state;

        if (dirX > 0f)
        {
            state = MovementState.running;
            sprite.flipX = false;
        }
        else if (dirX < 0f)
        {
            state = MovementState.running;
            sprite.flipX = true;
        }
        else
        {
            state = MovementState.idle;
        }

        if (rigidbody.velocity.y > .1f)
        {
            state = MovementState.jumping;
        }
        else if (rigidbody.velocity.y < -.1f)
        {
            state = MovementState.falling;
        }

        animator.SetInteger("state", (int)state);
    }

    private bool IsGrounded()
    {
       return Physics2D.BoxCast(collider.bounds.center, collider.bounds.size, 0f, Vector2.down, .1f, jumpableGround);
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Added a fix to the IsGrounded method.

Comment: The double jump is now working but when the player reaches the ground he is not able to jump again. Do you know how can I solve that?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to call the IsGrounded function, in the Update method you to ask if Player is grounded, if true, set jumpCounter to 0. I already edit the code.

Maybe you need to check the OnCollisionEnter2D Unity Method, to check if player is on ground for futures projects, it's more optimizated
[Unity Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.OnCollisionEnter2D.html)